# Ruby: Multiple module declaration

Tags: ruby

I am trying to understand a piece of code with multiple modules

```
module a; module b; module c;

def foo
    #something 
end

end
end
end
```

So what exactly does the above code mean? Is it like all 3 modules have foo and I can access a.foo or b.foo etc..?

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Comment: `SyntaxError: class/module name must be CONSTANT`

Comment: please do indent your code, and follow any ruby modules, classes tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see how that would be confusing. It is very badly laid out. Split the module declarations onto separate lines and it makes more sense.  Ruby allows some things to be separated by semicolons if written on one line... that is being abused here and just leads to confusion.

The code expands to this, when correctly laid out:

```
module a
  module b
    module c
      def foo
        #something 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Other examples of using a semicolon to write a definition on a single line include:

```
class Foo < Bar; def zip; if @terrifying; puts "Yes"; else; puts "No"; end; end; end
```

You can probably see why I say this isn't well written.  Also, the module names should begin with an Uppercase letter.

Comment: Thanks, I guess laying out code with indention rather than one liners is better (for a beginner).