# Module structures, What is it meant by Module A Module B Module C in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, module

I am new to Ruby and looking at a source code.  I see it says on top

```
module a module b module c
 module d

  def foobar
```

From looking up what a module is, it is similar to class.  I have seen examples of

```
module a
 module b
  def foobar
```

where a module is defined in module, which i understand this concept but i do not get the chain of modules.

Also, i have seen it as

```
module a; module b;
module c
 def foorbar
```

why is there semicolon now?

Comment: A `module Something` is a statement, which starts the scope for a module of that name. Statements in Ruby are either separated by writing them on separate lines, or by writing a semicolon in between. Aside from this, `module a` is illegal anyway, because the module name must be a constant. You would have to write i.e. `module A`.

Comment: _"i do not get the chain of modules"_ – what chain are you referring to? _"Also, i have seen it as `module a; module b;`"_ – that example doesn't seem to make much sense, do you have a link to the actual code?

Comment: @Stefan similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858741/ruby-multiple-module-declaration 

module a; module b; module c;
 but instead there is no semicolon
module a module b module c

Comment: And where did you see that one without semicolons?

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid Ruby:

```
module a module b module c
```

This is potentially valid namespacing, although in Ruby all module and class names (but not methods) must be constants. In this case, that means they need to start with capital letters. The modules also need to be closed with end statements:

```
module A
  module B
    def foobar
    end
  end
end
```

Semicolons denote a break between statements. Sometimes people will use them to keep things shorter or for cut-and-paste into a REPL like IRB, but it's not good coding practice. For example, this is a valid one-line that does the same as above:

```
module A; module B; def foobar; end; end; end
```

If you work in IRB on a recent version of Ruby like 3.1.2, you'll even get useful exceptions that tell you what's wrong with your code:

> ```
> class/module name must be CONSTANT (SyntaxError)  
> module a  
>        ^
> ```

I suggest reading up on [Ruby syntax](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax_rdoc.html) and testing out code in a REPL like IRB (which comes standard with Ruby) or [TryRuby](https://try.ruby-lang.org/) online.

Comment: the module A module B module C
does eventually have end end end at the end of the file.  That means they are namespaces?

Comment: @leon Yes and no. Modules can act as namespaces, but they also provide other functionality like mixins, utility methods, module methods, and some class-like behaviors. So, they're more than just namespaces, but there are too many different use cases for them for a simple answer.